# Converting Docx to text only returning last line of text

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to convert word docx to text which is working properly. The issue is that when I try to return the argument I am only getting the last line of the converted text. However when I print it, it prints all of the completed text.

```
def word_text(test):
    for table in tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    print (paragraph.text.encode("utf-8"))
                    return (paragraph.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can `return` only once. Once it is `return`ed, it will not come back.

So i would suggest you to use `list` and add your `text` to that `list` and then `return list` at the last.